# ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat"

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jenkins

I am using Jenkins to build a python (Flask) solution to deploy to Google App Engine. As part of the build process I run a few integration tests.

One of them is failing with the following error.

```
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 420, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose-1.3.6-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/Tests/test_integration.py", line 4, in <module>
    from main import app
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    from Routes.AdminRoutes import admin_routes
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/Routes/AdminRoutes.py", line 7, in <module>
    from thirdpartylib import cloudstorage
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/thirdpartylib/cloudstorage/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from cloudstorage_api import *
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/thirdpartylib/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py", line 37, in <module>
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/cElementTree.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _elementtree import *
ImportError: PyCapsule_Import could not import module "pyexpat"
```

I have logged onto the VM and searched for this module and this is what i get

```
xxx@jenkins-pre1:~$ sudo find / -name pyexpat*
/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.so
/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/d0cfa9780fa540e496fd60e38f32c58708374a4a62bc8a6462834c7757a31cdf/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dy
nload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

I guess its install but the module cannot be imported. Please help.

The module is in the python path.

```
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-15.2-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/no
se-1.3.6-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/
python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'
, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
>>>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: Nope. I had to remove the test which dependant on the module.

Answer (score 6):

I found a workaround to this issue:

In your jenkins script, just clear LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable at the beginning:

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""

This does the trick!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/` is not in your Python's path.
You can check this with the following Python commands:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If it does not appear, you can set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/
```

Please make sure to check whether the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable is empty or not, if it is empty, please copy the values of the `sys.path` separated by "`:`" to it.

Hope I helped.

Comment: it is in the path. I have amended the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got this error after I install caffe on UBUNTU 16.04 with gcc 5.4

This works for me:

```
pip uninstall scikit-image

sudo apt-get install python-skimage
```

However above didn't work on another machine which also has this problem:

This works:

```
ldd /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.x86_64-linux-gnu.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa4570000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3ff57dc000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3ff5416000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f3ff52e5000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005645018a1000)
#and just rename that libexpat.so.1
cd /opt/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib
sudo mv libexpat.so.1 libexpat.so.1.bak
```

Taken from: http://answers.ros.org/question/227788/pycapsule_import-could-not-import-module-pyexpat-when-running-rosdep-update/?answer=229807